# neo4j configuration for junit and passing arraylist instance in cypher query

Tags: mysql, arraylist, junit, spring-data-neo4j

This is my case am retrieving a data through MySQL and save it in a ArrayList object, I need the same object into the cypher query ,am running my program with a junit test `public class DummyTest {

```
@Test
@Rollback(true)
public void checkMysqlConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet tableDatasRsult = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user", "root");
        properties.setProperty("password", "root");
        String url = "127.0.0.1:3306/unicity";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + url, properties);
        Assert.assertNotNull(connection);
        String sqlq = "select DIST_ID,PV_DATE,POST_DATE from odh";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlq);
        tableDatasRsult = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<OdhDO> odhDOs = new ArrayList<>();
        while (tableDatasRsult.next()) {
            OdhDO odhDO = new OdhDO();
            odhDO.setDistId(tableDatasRsult.getLong("DIST_ID"));
            odhDO.setPvDate(tableDatasRsult.getString("PV_DATE"));
            odhDO.setPostDate(tableDatasRsult.getString("POST_DATE"));
            odhDOs.add(odhDO);

            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(odhDO.getDistId().toString(), odhDO);
            System.out.println(params);

        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("MySql Driver Class Not Found Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Sql Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@Test
@Rollback(true)

public void checkneo4jConnection(){

    String URL= "http://localhost:7474";
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.driverConfiguration().setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver").setURI(URL).setCredentials("neo4j", "admin");


    String cypher = "MATCH (Distributor) WHERE Distributor.DISTID IN {odhDOs} RETURN Distributor";      
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> odhDOs = new ArrayList<>();
    params.put("odhDOs", odhDOs);

    //add some names to the names list
    //params.put(key, value)

    }`
```

In the above code in **checkMysqlConnection()** method i have retrieved the data and save this data in a **ArrayList odhDOs = new ArrayList<>()** object, i need to pass this Arraylist instance in a cypher query, but i dont know how to configure and connect neo4j from this class and how can i pass this arraylist instance inside the query 
**"MATCH (Distributor) WHERE Distributor.DISTID IN {odhDOs} RETURN Distributor**"
 please help with the configuration of junit with neo4j and how to pass the array instance in the cypher query..thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have a class called `Distributor` annotated with `@NodeEntity` as per the Neo4j-OGM documentation? https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm

Comment: Yes i have Distributor classas per the OGM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set up everything properly according to the documentation in the [OGM reference guide](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/) then something like this should work:

```
@Test
public void checkneo4jConnection(){

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.driverConfiguration()
        .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver")
        .setURI("http://localhost:7474")
        .setCredentials("neo4j", "admin");


    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(configuration, "package.where.your.distributor.class.is");

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    String cypher = "MATCH (Distributor) WHERE Distributor.DISTID IN {odhDOs} RETURN Distributor";      
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("odhDOs", Arrays.asList(new String[] {"odhDO1", "odhDO2"});

    // NOTE: If more than one result use session.query(). 
    //       If just one, use session.queryForObject()
    Iterable<Distributor> distributors = session.query(Distributor.class, cypher, params);

    for (Distributor distributor: distributors) {
        System.out.println(distributor.getDISTID());
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK U , I TRIED THIS WORKING FINE